# Join two sorted files using Hive/Hadoop

Tags: performance, sorting, hadoop, hive, etl

I have two sorted files and i need to join using hive or hadoop and aggregate by a key.
File A is sorted by (A.X, A.Y) and File B is sorted by (B.X, B.Y). I can make join using hive, create a intermediate result and then execute another query to sum values. What is the best way to make this operation? Doing  a mapreduce job or using hive? The file B is much smaller then file A. Can i use on my favor the fact that file A and file B are sorted?

```
FILE A       FILE B    INTERMEDIATE_FILE   FINAL_FILE
X Y  Z       X Y       X Y  Z              X Y   
1 V1 10      1 V1      1 V1 10             1 30 (20 + 10)
1 V1 20      2 V2      1 V1 20             2 50 (50)
1 V2 30      3 V1      2 V2 50             3 130 (60 + 70)
2 V1 40                3 V1 60
2 V2 50                3 V1 70
3 V1 60                
3 V1 70
4 V1 80
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can join the data using 'merge' option in pig.

Example:

```
data_a = load '$input1' as (X, Y, Z);
data_b = load '$input2' as (P, Q);
join_data = join data_a by (X,Y), data_b by (P,Q) using 'merge';
```

Perform your aggregation logic on join_data relation.

This is a sort-merge join operation. The join can be done in the map phase by opening both files and walking through them. Pig refers to this as a merge join because it is a sort-merge join, but the sort has already been done.

Source: Programming Pig by Alan Gates.

Comment: I dont think it is going to scale. The join is going to be performa using just one mapper, getting records over the network.

Answer (score 0):

I create an Identy Mapper Reducer job, and then execute another job using CompositeInputFormat. In the map phase, i made the calculation, using a pattern called "In-mapper Combiner". So, this secod job has no reducer. I think this is solution is goind to scale linearly. So if i double the size of my cluste, my job is goind to finish in a half of time.